# Table heading and table contents are not aligned in Angular using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I have created a table with 3 columns and the column headings are "Name", "Age" and "Deaprtment" and I assingn the values to their respective columns, I have put a condition using span if condition is removed the table heading and content is aligned if the condition is put then column heading and contents are not aligned. in app.component.html file

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="p-1" *ngFor="let column of columns">
      {{ column }}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let value of newNames">
    <span *ngIf="value.name != 'Max'">
      <td class="p-1">
       {{value.name}}
      </td>
      <td class="p-1">
        {{value.age}}
       </td>
      <td class="p-1">
        {{value.department}}
       </td>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="value.name == 'Max'">
      <td class="p-1">
       {{value.name}}
      </td>
      <td class="p-1">
        {{value.age}}
       </td>
      <td class="p-1">
        {{value.department + " changed to" + " IT"}}
       </td>
    </span>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

In app.component.ts file I have added the following line of code.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "app-root",
templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
columns = ["Name", " Age", "Department"];
newNames = [
{
  name: "John",
  age: 28,
  department: "Accounting"
},
{
  name: "Max",
  age: 26,
  department: "Sports"
},
{
  name: "Rose",
  age: 24,
  department: "Arts"
}
];
}
```

and in component.scss i have added

```
 @import "../styles.scss";

.table thead th {
 vertical-align: top;
 }

 th {
 white-space: nowrap;
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select: none;
 color: grey;
 }

 table {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "Lato";
 font-size: 12px;
 }

 .table-responsive {
 min-height: 60px;
 }

 .cell {
  max-width: 250px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }

 .table thead th {
 vertical-align: top;
 }
```

can some one help me how to align the table content with table heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `span` tag inside `tr` tag.

There's dedicated Angular tag for such purposes that doesn't break markup - `ng-container`.

So, your solution is to replace `span` with `ng-container`

```
<tr *ngFor="let value of newNames">
  <ng-container *ngIf="value.name != 'Max'">
    ...
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="value.name == 'Max'">
    ...
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/nYrko0jv1oKIFFxvvFDF)**